# Playing Audio without silence between buffers AudioContext JS

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, buffer, web-audio-api

```
let socket = new WebSocket("WebSocket Address");

let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let audioCtx;

let buffers = [];
let channels = 1;

function init() {
    audioCtx = new AudioContext();
}

function playAudio(buffer) {
    if(!audioCtx) {
        init();
    }

    let frameCount = buffer.length;

    let myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(channels, frameCount, 44100);

    for (let channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
        let nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
        for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            nowBuffering[i] = buffer[i];
        }
    }

    source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start();

    source.onended = () => {
        buffers.shift();
        playAudio(buffers[0]);
    }
}

socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    var arr = event.data.split(" ");
    buffers.push(arr);
    
}
document.querySelector('#start').onclick = () => {
    playAudio(buffers[0]);
}
```

I wrote a program that decodes an audio file and sends a 44100 number (-1 to 1) audio buffer string via sockets.

In JavaScript, I wrote this code to get a string, turn it into an array, and play it back. But when the playSound function is called again, the sound disappears for a couple of milliseconds.

Is there any way or ideas how I can make the playback smooth and lag free?

Comment: Is this lag also there when song played first time ?

Comment: @PawanBishnoi Yes, it lags when playing different files and from different devices

Comment: So you can store the current playing song in memory as a cache and if user plays same song again then you can play it directly from memory instead of creating buffer again, i hope then there will be no lag for same song in queue.